# Time series data interpolation in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have a time series data in R. The data are in the following format:

```
datetime value
2012-04-18 14:22:09   342.82
2012-04-18 14:22:11   345.14
2012-04-18 14:22:12   341.68
2012-04-18 14:22:15   342.21
2012-04-18 14:22:16   342.36
```

The data are collected with frequency of 1 second, but some values are missing (for example the values of 2012-04-18 14:22:10, 2012-04-18 14:22:13, 2012-04-18 14:22:14). I just want to get these data added to the series by interpolation. How can I do this in R?

I tried this:

```
y <- zoo(x, frequency=1);
```

but I didn't get what I wanted.

Thanks!

Comment: See `na.approx` in the `zoo` package and [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073686/interpolating-timeseries).

Comment: There's nothing about resampling in this question.