# Time Series Interpolation

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, interpolation, zoo

I have two series of data (calibration and sample) and am trying to interpolate the calibration data from monthly to the frequency of the sample which randomly changes between minutes to seconds.

I tried this ([Interpolating timeseries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13073686/interpolating-timeseries)) and here's my code:

```
     require(zoo)
     
     zc <- zoo(calib$MW2, calib$Date)    
     zs <- zoo(sample$MW.2, sample$DateMW.2)

     z <- merge(zc, zs)

     zc <- zoo(calib$MW2, calib$Date)   
     zs <- zoo(sample$MW.2, sample$DateMW.2)  
     
     # "merge" gets data frames only
     zc <- data.frame(zc)
     zs <- data.frame(zs)

     z <- merge(zc, zs)

     z$zc <- na.approx(z$zc, rule=2)

     df <- z[index(zs),]
```

***Note:*** Convert outputs of `zoo` to `data.frame` (`zc` and `zs`) before merging.

The problem is that instead of interpolation, it just repeats the calibration data-set; You can take a look at the part of the supposedly interpolated `df` and compare it to the original data above to confirm what I say;

```
     > df
        zc       zs                date     
     1     60.84440 61.40373 2016-06-02 18:15:00
     2     58.85957 61.40373 2016-06-02 18:30:00
     3     57.49543 61.40373 2016-06-02 18:45:00
     4     56.32829 61.40373 2016-06-02 19:00:00
     5     56.84261 61.40373 2016-06-02 19:15:00
     6     57.76762 61.40373 2016-06-02 19:30:00
     7     59.58310 61.40373 2016-06-02 19:45:00
     8     59.95826 61.40373 2016-06-02 20:00:00
     9     60.84440 61.41549 2016-06-02 20:15:00
     10    58.85957 61.41549 2016-06-02 20:30:00
     11    57.49543 61.41549 2016-06-02 20:45:00
     12    56.32829 61.41549 2016-06-02 21:00:00
```

#Data:

```
     sample <- structure(list(DateMW.2 = structure(1:15, .Label = c("6/2/2016 18:15:00", 
     "6/2/2016 18:30:00", "6/2/2016 18:45:00", "6/2/2016 19:00:00", 
     "6/2/2016 19:15:00", "6/2/2016 19:30:00", "6/2/2016 19:45:00", 
     "6/2/2016 20:00:00", "6/2/2016 20:15:00", "6/2/2016 20:30:00", 
     "6/2/2016 20:45:00", "6/2/2016 21:00:00", "6/2/2016 21:15:00", 
     "6/2/2016 21:30:00", "6/2/2016 21:45:00"), class = "factor"), 
     MW.2 = c(61.40373, 61.41549, 61.41549, 61.42451, 61.42752, 
     61.42478, 61.43107, 61.42369, 61.40564, 61.41056, 61.40592, 
     61.39416, 61.38432, 61.3753, 61.3753)), .Names = c("DateMW.2", 
     "MW.2"), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")


     calib <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 
     3L), .Label = c("10/31/2016 12:00:00", "11/30/2016 12:00:00", 
     "12/31/2016 12:00:00", "5/31/2016 12:00:00", "6/30/2016 12:00:00", 
     "7/31/2016 12:00:00", "8/31/2016 12:00:00", "9/30/2016 12:00:00"
     ), class = "factor"), MW2 = c(60.844402, 58.859566, 57.495434, 
     56.328285, 56.842606, 57.76762, 59.583103, 59.958263)), .Names = c("Date",     
     "MW2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: Do `head(z)` and check that it does, as you seem to believe, have columns zc and zs in it. Also, why are you repeating those lines in the middle? And maybe don't call another variable big Z, that will confuse us all.

Comment: @dash2 I should have stated it more clearly. But the problem is with merging. I will edit the question.

Comment: Thanks! The error seems to derive from all values beeing `NA`.

Comment: @lukeA YES. Apparently something happens when I try to merge them.

Comment: What would you expect the result of `merge(zc, zs)` in your example to be?

Comment: Yeah, think you are using `merge` when you want `cbind`

Comment: @dash2 `cbind` will give the exact same result. It's still all NAs.

Comment: @dash2 update on using `cbind`: it works on data frames with same size. The problem with `merge` was that it takes data-frames and output of zoo was not df. I updated the code and it now does not return NAs but the interpolation result is bizarre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data-set is already formatted as date-time you don't need to struggle with using `zoo`. Here, I simply used `approx` function and it gave me exactly what I wanted. You can get the data-set from the question to reproduce the code.

```
       ipc <- approx(calib$Date,calib$MW2, xout = sample$`DateMW-2`, 
       rule = 1, method = "linear", ties = mean)
```

You can see that the data is being interpolated linearly between the given data points.

[image]

Thanks for your insightful comments.