# Expanding R Matrix on Date

Tags: r, date, dataframe, time-series, interpolation

I have the following R matrix:

```
Date MyVal
2016  1
2017  2
2018  3
....
2026  10
```

What I want to do is "blow it up" so that it goes like this (where monthly values are linearly interpolated):

```
Date        MyVal
01/01/2016    1
02/01/2016    ..
....
01/01/2017    2
....
01/01/2026    10
```

I realize I can easily generate the sequence using:

```
DateVec <- seq(as.Date(paste(minYear,"/01/01", sep = "")), as.Date(paste(maxYear, "/01/01", sep = "")), by = "month")
```

And I can use that to make a large matrix and then fill things in using a for loop over the DateVector in but I wonder if there's a more elegant R way to do this?

Comment: have a look at `?merge`

Comment: If you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) I can check the solution on it.

Comment: Check the solution below. Meanwhile, it needs some modification (not to the last line but to the data-frame preparation part) based on exact structure of your dataset.

Comment: @HubertL I am curious about how to use `merge` for interpolation. This is [one of my first questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42938001/time-series-interpolation). I was at first trying to use `zoo` and `merge` for it but ended up with `approx` (using `merge` I was getting y values repeated instead of interpolated). Would you take a look at it to see if you can provide a solution with that approach? Will be happy to accept it. Also, it can be helpful for this question as they fall into the same category (time series interpolation).

Comment: You're right @Masoud, I missed the "interpolated"... so did OP's example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stats::approx`:

```
library(stats)

ipc <- approx(df$Date, df$MyVal, xout = DateVec, 
rule = 1, method = "linear", ties = mean)
```

You probably need to first convert the data in your original data-frame to have month and day and also be in `asPOSIXct` or `as.Date` format.

Based on what you provided, this works:

```
#Make the reference data-frame for interpolation:
DateVec <- seq(min(df$Date, na.rm=T), 
               max(df$Date, na.rm=T), by = "month")

#Interpolation:
intrpltd_df <- approx(df$Date, df$MyVal, xout = DateVec, 
          rule = 1, method = "linear", ties = mean)

#            x        y 
# 1 2016-01-01 1.000000 
# 2 2016-02-01 1.084699 
# 3 2016-03-01 1.163934 
# 4 2016-04-01 1.248634 
# 5 2016-05-01 1.330601 
# 6 2016-06-01 1.415301
```

***Data:***

```
#reproducing the data-frame:
Date <- seq(2016,2026)
MyVal <- seq(1:11)
Date <- data.frame(as.Date(paste0(Date,"/01/01"))) #yyyy-mm-dd format
df <- cbind(Date, MyVal)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
colnames(df) <- c ("Date", "MyVal") #Changing Column Names
```